# Not remove empty notes when its save

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Problem:** The problem is when i create multiple note at a time like i create 3 notes in same time and i wrote same text in first note and save it, the remaining empty note will not be remove when it reload or refresh the page. So how can i achieve this when the notes is empty, it should be remove and it should not be saved in local storage only those noes will be saved when one is not empty.
You can run this code on your **local machine to see output.**

```js
const icon = document.getElementById('icon-plus');
const add = document.querySelector('#plus');

// const show = () => {
//     icon.style.display = "inline";
// }

// const hide = () => {
//     icon.style.display = "none";
// }

const hideBtn = () => {
    add.style.display = "none";
}

const showBtn = () => {
    add.style.display = "flex";
}

const updateLocalStorage = () => {
    const textAreaData = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    const notes = [];
    console.log(textAreaData);
    textAreaData.forEach((note) => {
        return notes.push(note.value);
    })

    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
    // textArea.disabled = true;
}

const addNewNote = (text = '') => {

    const note = document.createElement('div');
    note.classList.add('notes');

    const htmlData = `
              
            <div class="upper-icon">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </div>
            <div class="text-content">
            <div class="main" TextMode="MultiLine"">
            </div>
                <textarea id = "text-box" placeholder="Write a note..."  onmouseover="hideBtn()" onmouseout="showBtn()"></textarea>
            </div>
    `;

    note.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', htmlData);

    document.body.appendChild(note);

    //References //
    const edit = note.querySelector('.fa-edit');
    const del = note.querySelector('.fa-trash');
    const mainDiv = note.querySelector('.main');
    const textArea = note.querySelector('textarea');
    const save = note.querySelector('.fa-save');


    // Delete the note //

    del.addEventListener('click', () => {
        note.remove();
        updateLocalStorage();
    })


    //toggle using edit button //

    textArea.value = text;
    textArea.innerHTML = text;

    edit.addEventListener('click', () => {

        textArea.disabled = false;



        // textArea.classList.toggle('hidden');
    })

    save.addEventListener('click', () => {
        textArea.disabled = true;
        mainDiv.classList.toggle('hidden');
        updateLocalStorage();
     
         
    

        
    })


    textArea.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        // const value = event.target.value;
        textArea.innerHTML = event.target.value;;
        // if (textArea.value.length > 0) {
        //     updateLocalStorage();
        // }
        updateLocalStorage();
     
    })

    if (textArea.value.length != 0) {
        textArea.disabled = true;
    }

}

// getting a data from local storage //
const notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
if (notes) {
    notes.forEach((note) => {
        addNewNote(note);
    })
}


add.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addNewNote()
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'KoHo', sans-serif;

}

body{
    background: #1e272e;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

header{
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.5rem;
    background-color: orange;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0,0,0.4 );
    user-select: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;

}

header .nav{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

header .nav h2{
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.button{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 30px;
    user-select: none;
 
}

.button button{
    display: flex;
    width: 152px;
    height: 45px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #1e272e;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px black , 0px 0px 1px 1px black;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 50px;
    bottom: 35px;
 
}

.button .icon i{
    font-size: 23px;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
}



.button button h3{
    margin-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 0px;
}

.button button:active{
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px black, inset 1px 1px 1px  black;
}

.button button h3:hover{
    color: black;
}
.button button:hover{
    background-color: orange;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transform: scale(1.08) translateY(-15px);
    transition: all 0.3 ease-in-out;
   
}


.notes{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.notes .upper-icon{
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-left:20px ;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

.notes .upper-icon i{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.notes .text-content{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px 0px 40px 20px;    
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0,0,0.6 ), 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0,0,0.5);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;

}

/* .notes .main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
} */
.notes  textarea{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey; 
    resize:  none;
    border: 1px solid wheat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0,0,0.6 ), 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0,0,0.5);
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    outline: none;
}

.notes .upper-icon i.fa-edit:hover{
    color: orange;
}

.notes .upper-icon i.fa-trash:hover{
    color: red;
}

.notes .upper-icon i.fa-save:hover{
    color: green;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px){

    
    .notes{
        margin: 40px 25px 0px 25px;
    }

    .button button{
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        bottom: 70px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: orange;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        right: 40px;
    }

    .button button h3{
        display: none;
    }

    .button button .icon i{
        display: flex;
        margin-top: -10px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .button button:hover{
        transform: scale(1);   
    }
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .notes{
        margin: 40px 25px 0px 20px;
    }

    .button button{
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        bottom: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: orange;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
        right: 20px
    }

    .button button .icon i{
        display: flex;
        margin-top: -10px;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .button button:hover{
        transform: scale(1);   
    }

}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Keep Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=KoHo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="nav">
            <i class="far fa-sticky-note fa-2x"></i>
            <h2>Keep Notes</h2>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="button">
        <button id="plus">
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fas fa-plus" id="icon-plus"></i>
            </div>

            <h3>Add a Note</h3>
        </button>

    </div>

    <footer>Copyright &copy; 2021 Ankit Shrestha</footer>
    <script src="javaScript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating the notes to localstorage,we need to check whether the notes is having a value or not(i.e; empty).If it is not empty,then onl we should push the notes to localstorage.

```js
const updateLocalStorage = () => {
    const textAreaData = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    const notes = [];
    console.log(textAreaData);
    textAreaData.forEach((note) => {
        if(note.value){
            return notes.push(note.value);}
        })
```

Comment: There is one little issue, **i gave the codition when notes will be push is if ( note.value == true and save button will also be clicked ) then push...**
Only those note will be push which notes save button is clicked or pressed and  those notes will not be save whose save button is not clicked..